# Lenovo U310 Touch Partitioning

Tags: mount, lenovo

I have a Lenovo U310 that comes with an 50 Gb SSD and 500 HDD. I installed ubuntu on the SSD. Basically the OS is on /dev/sda. I need to mount /dev/sdb. How can I format it and and mount because i will not have enough space on the /dev/sda for any installs and files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Format /dev/sdb e.g. to ext4.

You can mount it anywhere, e.g. `/media/HDD`. You need to create the `HDD` directory first by `sudo mkdir /media/HDD`.

You can also add it to `/etc/fstab` to be mounted automatically on boot.